# Stop score going negative and over 52

Tags: javascript, counter

I have a text based war game where the teams start with a score of 26 (userScore and computerScore).  When a player wins, it goes up and when a player loses, it goes down.

Problem is, the score goes negative and goes above 52 (in the event of a war at 51 cards), which would be all of the cards plus some (can't have more than 52 cards).

How can I limit userScore and computerScore from going negative or over 52?

```
var suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"];
var cards = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"];

var attempts = 1;
var war = false;

var computerScore = 26;
var userScore = 26;


while (computerScore < 52 && userScore < 52)
{

  var computerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
  var userIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);

  var computerCard = cards[computerIndex];
  var userCard = cards[userIndex];
  var computerSuit = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
  var userSuit = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];

  alert("I drew a " + computerCard + " of " + computerSuit +"\nYou drew a " + userCard + " of " + userSuit);

  if (computerIndex > userIndex && war == false)
  {
    computerScore++;
    userScore--;
    alert("I win. \n\nI have " + computerScore + " cards and you have " + userScore + " cards.");
  }

  else if (computerIndex < userIndex && war == false)
  {
    computerScore--;
    userScore++;
    alert("You win. \n\nI have " + computerScore + " cards and you have " + userScore + " cards.");
  }

  else if (computerIndex == userIndex && war == false)
  {
    alert("TIE! TIME FOR WAR! \n\nI have " + computerScore + " cards and you have " + userScore + " cards")
    war = true;

    var computerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
    var userIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);

    var computerCard = cards[computerIndex];
    var userCard = cards[userIndex];
    var computerSuit = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
    var userSuit = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];

    alert("I drew a " + computerCard + " of " + computerSuit +"\nYou drew a " + userCard + " of " + userSuit);

      if (computerIndex > userIndex && war == true)
          { 
            computerScore = computerScore + (attempts * 3);
            userScore = userScore - (attempts * 3);
            alert("I win. \n\nI have " + computerScore + " cards and you have " + userScore + " cards.");
            war = false;
            attempts = 1;
          }

          else if (computerIndex < userIndex && war == true)
          {
            userScore = userScore + (attempts * 3);
            computerScore = computerScore - (attempts * 3);
            alert("You win. \n\nI have " + computerScore + " cards and you have " + userScore + " cards.");
            war = false;
            attempts = 1;
          }

          else 
          {
            alert("TIE! TIME FOR WAR (AGAIN)! \n\nI have " + computerScore + " cards and you have " + userScore + " cards")
            attempts++;

            var computerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
            var userIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);

            var computerCard = cards[computerIndex];
            var userCard = cards[userIndex];
            var computerSuit = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
            var userSuit = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];

            alert("I drew a " + computerCard + " of " + computerSuit +"\nYou drew a " + userCard + " of " + userSuit);

            if (computerIndex == userIndex)
            {
              war = true;
            }

            else
            {
              war = false;
            }
          }
  }
}  

              if (computerScore >= 52)
                {
                  alert("I WIN!  GOOD GAME!");
                }
                  else
                {
                  alert("YOU WIN!  GOOD GAME!")
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using (cards.length) to compute the computerIndex and userIndex, while you should use (cards.length)-1, because arrays always starts from index 0 that's why the total cards exceeded 52 in the end. and Same for the Suit as well.
edit: To avoid the brackets being misplaced, just create a variable and use it as shown below:

```
<script>

alert("Hi. Let's Play War!");

var computerScore = 48;
var userScore = 4;

var suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"];
var cards = ["2", "3", "4"];

var attempts = 1;
var war = false;

function mathClampC(min,mid,max)
{
  var min = 0;
  var max = 52;
  var mid = computerScore;
  return Math.min(Math.max(min,mid),max);
}

function mathClampU(min,mid,max)
{

  var min = 0;
  var max = 52;
  var mid = userScore;
  return Math.min(Math.max(min,mid),max);
}

while (computerScore < 52 && userScore < 52)
{
  var computerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
  var userIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);

  var computerCard = cards[computerIndex];
  var userCard = cards[userIndex];
  var computerSuit = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
  var userSuit = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];

  alert("I drew a " + computerCard + " of " + computerSuit +"\nYou drew a " + userCard + " of " + userSuit);

  if (computerIndex > userIndex && war == false)
  {
    computerScore++;
    userScore--;
    alert("I win. \n\nI have " + mathClampC() + " cards and you have " + mathClampU() + " cards.");
  }

  else if (computerIndex < userIndex && war == false)
  {
    computerScore--;
    userScore++;
    alert("You win. \n\nI have " + mathClampC() + " cards and you have " + mathClampU() + " cards.");
  }

  else if (computerIndex == userIndex && war == false)
  {
    alert("TIE! TIME FOR WAR! \n\nI have " + mathClampC() + " cards and you have " + mathClampU() + " cards")
    war = true;

    var computerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
    var userIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);

    var computerCard = cards[computerIndex];
    var userCard = cards[userIndex];
    var computerSuit = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];
    var userSuit = suits[Math.floor(Math.random()*suits.length)];

    alert("I drew a " + computerCard + " of " + computerSuit +"\nYou drew a " + userCard + " of " + userSuit);

      if (computerIndex > userIndex && war == true)
          { 
            computerScore = computerScore + (attempts * 3);
            userScore = userScore - (attempts * 3);
            alert("I win. \n\nI have " + mathClampC() + " cards and you have " + mathClampU() + " cards.");
            war = false;
          }

          else if (computerIndex < userIndex && war == true)
          {
            userScore = userScore + (attempts * 3);
            computerScore = computerScore - (attempts * 3);
            alert("You win. \n\nI have " + mathClampC() + " cards and you have " + mathClampU() + " cards.");
            war = false;
          }

          else if (computerIndex == userIndex || war == true)
          {
            alert("TIE! TIME FOR WAR (AGAIN)! \n\nI have " + mathClampC() + " cards and you have " + mathClampU() + " cards")
            attempts++;

            if (computerIndex == userIndex) 
            {
              war = true;
            }

            else 
            {
              war = false;
            }
          }
  }
}  

              if (computerScore >= 52)
                {
                  alert("I WIN!  GOOD GAME!");
                }
                  else
                {
                  alert("YOU WIN!  GOOD GAME!")
                }

</script>
```

Comment: That does fix the going over 52, but I now receive an "undefined" in the alert for the number of the card (I drew a undefined of Spades, for example).

Comment: yes, I get undefined messages for the suit and card number (not always, but at some points).

Comment: Just to avoid the brackets being misplaced, I've edited my answer. I didn't faced any undefined messages.

Comment: Just tried TheUnknown's new solution (adding a variable) through a couple of tests.  Still getting 53 cards and -1 cards.

Comment: I ran it like 5 times, I get 52 and 0 in the end. Are you running this on Google Chrome? Let's see if someone else gives some reviews.

Comment: I am using Chrome.  You will get 52 and 0 when it works our perfectly to finish at 52.  The problem is there are scenarios where you could get 53 cards (a war when your score is currently 51).

Comment: @jjamboree can you try to edit your while loop with this? `while (computerScore < 52 && userScore < 52 && computerScore >=0 && userScore >=0)`

Comment: I've got it.  Just figured it out about five minutes ago and have been testing.  

Created a clamp function for the score and it displays properly.  See edit in code.